# ValueError: Input signal length=2 is too small to resample from 44100->16000

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, sampling, librosa

I am trying to read some audio wav files and everything was perfect until I added some more audio files I faced an error. The reading audio files and resampling it to 16KHz using the following code

```
def speech_file_to_array_fn(batch):
    start = 0 
    stop = 20 
    srate = 16_000
    speech_array, sampling_rate = sf.read(batch["file"], start = start * srate , stop = stop * srate)
    batch["speech"] = librosa.resample(np.asarray(speech_array), sampling_rate, srate)
    batch["sampling_rate"] = srate
    batch["parent"] = batch["label"]
    return batch
```

I am receiving this error:

```
ValueError: Input signal length=2 is too small to resample from 44100->16000
```

I tried transposing the audio file after reading it but didn't work

Thanks

Comment: python is not my language however `srate = 16_000`  seems strange ... what is the underbar doing there ?

Comment: I removed it and Still facing the same error

Comment: Underscore in a number is fine in python, i.e. `16_000 == 16000 >>> True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/915) over on the GitHub for `librosa`.

I've never used the library before but it looks like, from [this comment](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/915#issuecomment-508760896), that in your case you could just do the following:

```
def speech_file_to_array_fn(batch):
    start = 0 
    stop = 20 
    srate = 16_000
    speech_array, sampling_rate = sf.read(batch["file"], start = start * srate , stop = stop * srate)
    speech_array = speech_array.T
    batch["speech"] = librosa.resample(np.asarray(speech_array), sampling_rate, srate)
    batch["sampling_rate"] = srate
    batch["parent"] = batch["label"]
    return batch
```

Let me know if this works as I have no way to test it.